# Choose one element in arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, random

I have `N` groups of arrays. Each group contains 3 arrays for example.
Now I would like to take only one array from each of these groups and take a product with `B` array.

**For example:**

- `A` 3D array is given, `2x2x32`.
- I split `A` and get `B_i` ( 2 x 2 x 8), 3D array too, but `i=1,..., 8`. It means `B_i` is formed as a slices of `A`.
- Each `B_i` has sub-arrays, 2 D arrays 2x2 :`C_k`.

```
B_1(:,:,m)=C_1, where m is size( B_i, 3)
```

In each B_i there are 8 sub-array C_k. I am looking for an algorithm that helps me to take random one of them (one of C_k) and use it later for another computation.

How can I implement random choosing of the array in B_i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a random column, with index `1, 2, 3`. Thus, don't set `numel(A)` as your max integer in `randi()`, instead, set it at `3`:

```
A = rand(2,2,3,5); % three 2-by-2 matrices, in each of 5 groups
B = rand(2,2); % Chosen for convenience; replace as warranted

% Preallocate C to have the same size as A_k * B, with as many groups
C = zeros([size(A,1),size(A,2),size(A,4)]);

for ii=1:size(A,4)  % Loop over all groups/slices
    % Choose a random column in {1, 2, 3} for each slice ii
    C(:,:,ii) = A(:,:,randi(3),ii)*B;
end
```

In this example there are 5 groups (fourth dimension of `A`), each group has three entries (third dimension), of 2 *-by-* 2 matrices (first two dimensions). Thus, loop over each group, the fourth dimension, choose a random `A` matrix through `randi(3)` on the third dimension, then multiply the remaining two dimensions with `B`, and store in `C`. `C` will have the dimensions of `A_k * B`, in this case chosen to be 2 *-by-* 2, and as third dimension the number of groups in `A`.

Comment: I have tried to add your suggestion in my simulation. And it doesn't work. Can you add an example how to use it?